# How to make Python file run by double-clicking on it in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python, executable

I make a game in Python with the `turtle` module but I want to make it executable by double clicking on it. I follow these steps:

1. My Python file has `#!/usr/bin/env python3` on top.
2. I created a file called `launcher.desktop` on the desktop. It contains:

   ```bsh
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name = Pong 
   Exec = /home/username/Desktop/MyGame/game.py 
   Version = 1.0 
   Icon = /home/username/Desktop/MyGame/game.icon 
   Type = Application
   ```
3. I marked the file as executable.

However, when I double-click on that file, it opens in text editor.

Can someone tell me how can I make the Python file executable by double-clicking in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Did the .desktop file change its icon to the game's icon when you marked it as executable?

Answer (score 2):

Your desktop file is basically correct, double clicking it will be interpreted as "edit" - you can see it in the properties - the default behavior of an icon on a desktop will be "Text editor".

I'd put it into `~/.local/share/applications`. Then you could start it from the activities.
Make sure the exec expression is executable. So your "game.py" must either be executable (then it needs the shebang  `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in its first line) or the exec must look like:

```
Exec= /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/mygames/game.py
```

Note that it would be good style to have the follwing line as **first** line in your desktop file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
```

And the "icon" should be rather *.png than ".icon".

So I called the game "pong":

[[image: 1]]

from where you could put it to your "favorites"

This is the complete desktop file as shown above:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name = Pong 
#Exec = /usr/bin/python3 /home/username/Desktop/games/game.py 
Exec = /home/username/Desktop/games/game.py 
Version = 1.0 
Icon = /home/username/Desktop/games/game.png
Type = Application
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Games
```

Comment: What a coincidence !!!! i Make the Pong Game xDDDD in python well thanks for help i upvote your post ^-^

Comment: Good News: It Worked :) Bad News: Sound Not Working :(

Comment: Then accept the answer, if it helped you. The sound problem would be a different question